# Using networkx and Dijkstras to find actual times instead of node count

Tags: python, graph, dijkstra

I apologize in advanced, I don't really know python, but I'm trying to use it along with this networkx library to find the distances between "BOS" Boston airport to all the other airports I have in a text file. I have:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()

code = []
name = []
longitude = []
latitude = []

rows = 0
with open("airport_info.txt") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    rows = len(content)
    for i in range(0, rows-1):
        columns = content[i].split(",")
        G.add_node(columns[0],pos=(float(columns[2]),float(columns[3].replace("\n",""))))

with open("flying_times.txt") as x:
    content = x.readlines()
    rows = len(content)
    for i in range(0,rows-1):
        columns = content[i].split(",")
        G.add_edge(columns[0],columns[1],weight=float(columns[2].replace("\n","")))

#print list(G.nodes())
#print list(G.edges())

#print nx.shortest_path_length(G,weight='weight')
print nx.shortest_path_length(G,"BOS")
```

This will give me the number of Nodes between BOS and every other airport, but how can I translate this into the actual distances (in hours) between BOS and each? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `nx.dijkstra_path_length`. In particular if you want to print all
the nodes distances this is what you need.

```
for target in G.nodes_iter():
    if target != 'BOS':
        print("Distance 'BOS' to '%s': %f" %
              (target, nx.dijkstra_path_length(G, "BOS", target)))
```

If you want the path you can instead use `nx.dijkstra_path`.

I think you might also run in some issues because `range` is not returning the value passed as `stop`, so you might be reading one line less then you expect; you should use `range(row)` (the `0` can be omitted). Anyway that code is not very pythonic, if you prefer you can use the following code:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
with open("airport_info.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
       code, lat, long = line.rstrip().split(",")
       G.add_node(code,pos=(float(lat),float(long)))

with open("flying_times.txt") as x:
    for line in x:
        source, target, distance = line.rstrip().split(",")
        G.add_edge(source, target, weight=float(distance))

for target in G.nodes_iter():
    if target != 'BOS':
        print("Distance 'BOS' to '%s': %f" %
              (target, nx.dijkstra_path_length(G, "BOS", target)))
```

**Final consideration**: you are using an undirected graph. This means that distances are always symmetric, and I don't know whether this is what you really need.